# How to create a layered PDF document using MapInfo version 12.5

Tags: mapinfo, pdf

I am wanting to create an interactive PDF layer using a MapInfo workspace where by layers can be turned on and off in the pdf. I also have a large aerial image I would like included in the pdf .

Any advice/ tips would be greatly apprecaited

Answer (score 3):

Once you've got a window set up that you want to print you can do this by going to File > Print To PDF. This will load the print dialog for the MapInfo PDF printer. Under the Properties button on the top right is a button labelled 'PDF'. Click it to access the PDF preferences dialog. Here you can set the output PDF to be layered, include attribute data, be georegistered, and to automatically open. Set it up how you want, click ok and print your PDF!